# Android:Unable to set ad in middle of the layout

Tags: android, admob

i have one main relative layout in that i have buttons and in middle i have image view i want to set my ad in center of the layout or screen. 
how to set it?

i am using the following code :

```
AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, publisher_code);
rl.addView(ad);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
ad.loadAd(request);
```

please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final RelativeLayout params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
r1.addView(ad,params);
```